# HTML make space smaller between elements

Tags: html, css

I have a `h2` element being displayed as a headline and under that headline I have a `h3` element.

The space between these two elements are too big for what I am doing. Is there anyway I can reduce the space between them with each element being on different lines?

Comment: Try changing the value of the margin between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `line-height:0.9em;`

Answer (score 0):

Use line-height for spaces between lines and letter-spacing for spaces between characters. For example:

Use

```
div { line-height: 0.9em;  letter-spacing:-5.5px; }
```

in your css if you are using one. And put your text in between .

Or do

```
<div style="line-height:0.9em">
//your text here
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this helped! :D. I'm new to CSS so I don't know all the things that you can do with it. Thank you for helping me solving this problem.

Comment: @TheDiamond06, if this helped you, make sure to "accept" the answer.